# Error with keystore : Parse Generalized time, invalid format

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

I get the following error when I to use my keystore :

```
$ keytool -list -keystore instavert.keystore

  keytool error : java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: Parse Generalized time, invalid format
```

I searched on Google and SO, but none of the solution worked...

Did anyone ever experienced the same issue?

Comment: Are you able to solve this? This happened to me also(on mac once) at that time i just thought some problems while creating .keystore file. SO I created one keystore file again with proper values. And then it was working.

Comment: @R.j., I had to create a new keystone from scratch and then it worked. I unfortunately had to discard my previous keystore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get this exception when you specified too big value for validity. Keytool does not do a great job on input validation when creating the keys and then it is not able to read the generated keystore. It is better to keep a backup from the keystore.